# graphics non existent in System.Drawing

Tags: c#, graphics, reference, drawing

while using System.Drawing, the PointF function works as intended however the Graphics, Brushes and Bitmap functions do not appear to exist.

[graphics not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWpZ4.png)

[using Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoW1M.png)

[font and brushes also dont work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKvX5.png)

[reference manager is empty (all 3 show the same thing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud3Ez.png)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly! How did you create the application?

Comment: i am very new to this, sorry for not understanding very well. i created using .NET framework console app in visual c# on windows classic desktop, .net framework 4.5

Comment: Well, basically Console is text only. It is possible to extend beyond that but for Graphics you will normally create a Winforms application. You could add more using clauses but mixing console and forms is not for newbies.

Comment: ohhh that makes sense, ill make it as a winforms application instead. thanks for getting back to me